# My Ubuntu VM is not rendering certain windows properly. Any help?

Tags: ubuntu, virtualbox

I'm running an Ubuntu VM on VirtualBox, but some windows just aren't loading properly. I attatched a screenshot of me trying to run gparted, but the alert window as well as the gparted window are unreadable. Any help would be greatly appreciated :-)

My display settings are:
Video Memory: 64MB
Graphics Controller: VMSVGA
Acceleration: 3D
Remote desktop server: Disabled
Recording: Disabled

[image]

Comment: Does it get better when you disable acceleration?

Comment: Did you install guest additions?